# How to protect an Express app by making the source code unreadable for human?

Tags: express, binary

I have tried to use Pkg and Nexe libraries, but I faced a died end in both libraries. I think they are not working properly on a big project. Is there a way to convert the source code and making it unreadable for the human?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with https://obfuscator.io/ (also in Github https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator)?